# XamlReader throwing up undeclared prefix error

Tags: c#, silverlight

I defined a resource as follows:

```
<DataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
            <Grid x:Name="grdArticle" Height="190" Width="190" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Source="samplePhoto.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Title}" Canvas.ZIndex="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="50" FontStyle="Normal">
                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#BFFFFFFF"/>
                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

When I'm trying to parse it using:

```
DataTemplate dtTmplt = XamlReader.Load(PhoneApp5.Resource1.Datatemplate_lst) as DataTemplate;
```

I'm getting XamlParseException,saying "undeclared prefix" at line 2,position 104.
I have tried many xmlns tags from the internet,but nothing seems to work.Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `toolkit` prefix that is undeclared.  You need to add

```
xmlns:toolkit="..."
```

to either the `<DataTemplate>` or the outer `<Grid>` element.  Replace `...` with whatever you're binding `xmlns:toolkit` to elsewhere in your application.

Incidentally, is there a reason you're parsing the contents of a resource as XAML this way?  Normally, I'd put a `DataTemplate` in a `Resources` resource-dictionary somewhere, or in `Application.Resources`.  That way, the compiler would check that it is valid XAML.

Comment: Thank you very much.This thing wasted my 4 hours.